# I am trying to translate this in to English sentence. Help needed

Tags: logic

*I will notate & for "and" and v for "or"*

> A: I got X
>   B: I went to school.

**~(A v B)** = *Neither I got X nor did I go to school.*

which is equivalent to **~A & ~B** = *I did not get X and I did not go to school*.

But what I have trouble with is

**~A v ~B** is *I did not get X or I did not go to school*.

which is equivalent to **~(A & B)**, but I do not know how to translate **~(A & B)** into an English sentence.

Can anyone help me?

Also, what is the difference between *Both I love 1 and I love 2* and *I love both 1 and 2*?

Are both sentences equal to **A & B** ?

Comment: & and ^ have the same meaning as conjunction in all notations I know. v means disjunction. I've edited for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**~(A & B)** is *It is not the case that I both got X and went to school.*  You would rarely hear a sentence like this in natural English, which is why it is hard to translate.

Both of your sentences could be expressed by **A & B** in a simple logic such as the one you're using.  If you were working with a predicate logic, the first would be **L(A) & L(B)**, the second would be **L(A & B)**.